# How to color specifics parts (letters) of menu?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Firstly, happy new year to you all! :)

Ok let's get to it. I have 5 items in my menu, and i would like to color "+" part of the word to red, choosing 2nd,3rd and 4th item of menu.

This is what menu looks like right now.

[image]

This is how the menu should look like, when its done.

[image]

I might have given a bad picture, but i think you can see the red "+" on 2nd,3rd and 4th item of menu.

This is what i've tried so far, but i can't seem to figure out the nth-child method.

```
#menu li:nth-child(2):first-letter a{color:red;}
```

Also tried this, but it colors every first letter in all 5 elements :S

```
#menu .nav > li > a:first-letter{color:red;}
```

[image]

Any help will be appreciated!

Thank you all!

**I've managed to find the solution. Not sure if it's the best one, but im posting it below, so that any1 in the future can use it too, if no other solution is found**

```
#menu .nav > li:nth-child(2) > a:first-letter
{
color:red;
}
#menu .nav > li:nth-child(3) > a:first-letter
{
color:red;
}
#menu .nav > li:nth-child(4) > a:first-letter
{
color:red;
}
```

Comment: Why not put that wanted character in a `span` and style that?

Comment: @Roope think it makes it even harder since this is opencart platform, and everything goes inside foreach loop, meaning <span>+</span> would make them all have +. Atleast i think so ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `:not()` selector to have all but `one` selected like this:

```css
#menu{
background: rgb(83,83,83);
width: 100vw;
height: 40px;  
}

ul{
text-align: center;
line-height: 40px;  
vertical-align: central;  
}

ul li{
display: inline-block;
color: white;  
list-style: none;  
margin-left: 25px;  
}

a{
color: white;
display: block;  
}

#menu ul li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) a::first-letter{
color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">+option</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">+option</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">+option</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">+option</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">+option</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you estaban, found solution like 2 mins ago, just before your post. As your post seems to be working, i'll mark your answer as the right one. Thanks for your input :)

Comment: You're welcome, although your posted solution requires a lot more lines of code, it is simpler. Just consider the fact that if your list grows, then you have to start adding more code, this solution takes all into account in one line. :)

Comment: yeh i do understand that. i'm still learning, and it usually takes me a lot more time and code to find answer, but i do get there at some point. im sure that one day when i get better, i'll be using less lines to find answer :P thank you and have a good day

Answer (score 1):

I know this question already has an accepted answer, but I think there is a semantically better way of doing this. Instead of having the `+` symbol inside the link's markup, why not add it as a pseudo `:before` element? Easier to style and not dependent on your markup.

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Domov</a></li>
    <li class="with-symbol"><a href="#">Naravni kamen</a></li>
    <li class="with-symbol"><a href="#">Dekorativni kamen</a></li>
    <li class="with-symbol"><a href="#">Keramika</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

And the respective CSS:

```
.with-symbol:before {
  content: '+';
  color: red;
}
```

Then position it with either `position: absolute;` or negative left margin.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Afirst-letter): A first line has meaning only in a block-container box, therefore the ::first-letter pseudo-element has an effect only on elements with a display value of block, inline-block, table-cell, list-item or table-caption. In all other cases, ::first-letter has no effect. So you will need to add display: block to your anchor tags.
I would also change the selector to:

```
ul li a:first-letter {
    color:red;
}
```

as you need to select the first letter of the anchor tag, not the list item.
As a side note, it might be a better solution to use a span as suggested above or pseudo elements to insert the plus character and use a class to determine if it should be displayed or no.

Comment: don't think the "block" was an issue, as display was already pointing to block. thank you anyway, i've found solution